# Read Yahoo or Google Finance API data into javascript object for use in google visualization chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am quite novice at javascript and web programming in general.
I'm trying to make a basic chart of stock prices using the Google Visualization Chart API.
My data is historical market data from either yahoo finance or google finance.

How do I read this finance data into a javascript object?

For example, using python I can read this data into a Dictionary or DataFrame object to store it before generating a chart from that python object. I want to do this with JS / Jquery / etc..

Here is a basic example of the code im trying to make work where im reading in a JSON response in this case from Google Finance for 1 day of stock price info:

```
function drawVisualization() {
   // How to get the stock data into my DataTable.?
    var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       // [ { "id": "694653" ,"t" : "GOOG" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "1,133.16" ,"l_fix" : "1133.16" ,"l_cur" : "1,133.16" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"1:11PM EST" ,"lt" : "Jan 7, 1:11PM EST" ,"c" : "+15.84" ,"c_fix" : "15.84" ,"cp" : "1.42" ,"cp_fix" : "1.42" ,"ccol" : "chg" } ]

    ], true);

    // Draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, {legend:'none', width:600, height:400});
}
```

​
So my question is how do I store the stock data in JavaScript, then how do I pass that data into google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() ?

Do i pass the URL directly? Or store the JSON object the URL returns in a variable then pass that into google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already input the data into javascript, you need to parse it into an appropriate format for the Visualization API DataTable (as the format implied by your code is not compatible).  You can parse it like this:

```
var financeData = /* finance data, assumed in this code to be an array of objects */;
var parsedData = [];

// create row of column headers
parsedData.push(['ID', 'ticker', 'exchange' /* ... filling out all columns you want to use */]);
// parse financeData
for (var i = 0; i < financeData.length; i++) {
    parsedData.push([financeData[i].id, financeData[i].t, financeData[i].e /* ... filling out all columns you want to use */]);
}
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsedData);
```

**[edit - example code for building a DataTable from Yahoo Finance data source using jQuery AJAX]**

```
function drawTable () {
    // use jQuery to make an AJAX request for data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Symbol');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
            data.addColumn('date', 'UTC Time');

            // parse the JSON into the DataTable
            for (var i = 0; i < json.list.resources.length; i++) {
                var name = json.list.resources[i].resource.fields.name;
                var symbol = json.list.resources[i].resource.fields.symbol;
                var price = parseFloat(json.list.resources[i].resource.fields.price);
                var dateTimeArr = json.list.resources[i].resource.fields.utctime.split('T');
                var dateArr = dateTimeArr[0].split('-');
                var year = dateArr[0];
                var month = dateArr[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to make compatible with javascript dates
                var day = dateArr[2];
                var timeArr = dateTimeArr[1].split(/[:\+]/);
                var hour = timeArr[0];
                var minute = timeArr[1];
                var second = timeArr[2];

                data.addRow([name, symbol, price, new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)]);
            }

            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.querySelector('#table_div'));
            table.draw(data);
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table'], callback: drawTable});
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/dSWe7/

Comment: Thanks. That helps alot, but im not there yet. Im still trying to get the data into javascript. How do I do that?

Comment: That depends on your data source.

Comment: Lets say from Yahoo Finance for example: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json  to get currency price data.  How do I get that data into JavaScript?  It returns JSON Format and their are multiple symbols being returned. I think Python Dictionary or DataFrame when I see JSON, but not sure about JS. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use AJAX to pull that data from Yahoo.  There are several javascript libraries that provide AJAX functions that handle the hard part for you; jQuery is probably the most commonly used one.  I'll update my answer with an example using jQuery.

Comment: how would I call the drawTable function on a button click? I have text input with a <button>. I use var symbol = $("#button").val() to store the symbol, then I put it in the URL: string.  How do I call the ajax on the button click?

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, the easiest way is to use the jQuery `click` method to attach a click event handler to the button: http://api.jquery.com/click/